# Finding the correct parameters for a file save

Tags: java, android, parameters

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to save a screenshot. I have this method that takes parameters Bitmap b and String strFileName. How does the system assign the string name for the file. And what do I need to place in the parameters for my savePic() call found in the onClick().

TAKE SCREEN SHOT METHOD:

```
public static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity)
{
    View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
    view.destroyDrawingCache();
    return b;
}
```

SAVE THE PIC METHOD:

```
public static void savePic(Bitmap b, String strFileName)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(strFileName);
        if (null != fos)
        {
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

onClick CALL of METHODS

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Call your methods

            takeScreenShot(MainActivity);
            savePic();

        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: are you need to save the image in specific place on device ??

Comment: @mohammedmomn Maybe show up in the downloads or similar. How do I control this and have it automatically assign a filename?

Comment: sorry i don't get the idea could you explain more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the reference to the bitmap that your takeScreenShot() method returns. Then pass that bitmap reference to savePic() along with a filename. A simple solution would be:

```
Bitmap screenShot = takeScreenShot(MainActivity);
String filename = "my_screenshot.png";
savePic(screenShot, filename);
```

Note that you have to provide the filename. The problem with the above is that each screenshot you save will overwrite the previous one. A common approach to generate unique filenames is to append a timestamp to the filename. For example:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hhmmss");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
String filename = "my_screenshot_" + formattedDate + ".png";
```

In your savePic() method, you aren't specifying where to save the file. By default it should save to the internal storage 'files' folder for your application, however you should explicity state where to save it. For example this will ensure it saves to that location:

```
File f = new File(getFilesDir(), strFileName);
fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

If you wanted to save to the public downloads folder instead:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), strFileName);
```

The following links give more information about the various places you can save your files and data to:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html